# C++/CLI - Update a custom control from a parent form "for loop" does not work

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

Rewriting the question with more clarity.

I have a WinForm that consists of a UserControl called ProgressTracker that shows the user a status message and completion % using labels in a TableLayoutPanel. The progress update usually comes from events getting fired in the MainForm that further call their respective methods. I was testing the ProgressTracker today by the following methods.

```
ProgressTracker^ pt; //Gets allocated when InitializeComponent() is called as it is added using the designer.

System::Void MainForm::Process()
{
    pt->TaskComplete = false;

    pt->CurrentStage = 0;
    pt->MaximumStage = 15;
    pt->Percentage = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        pt->CurrentStage = i; //integer property in ProgressTracker that further calls label->Text property.
        pt->Percentage = i;  //integer property in ProgressTracker that further calls label->Text property.
        pt->StatusMessage  //integer property in ProgressTracker that further calls label->Text property.
        System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(300);
    }

    pt->TaskComplete = true;
}
System::Void MainForm::ButtonClick(some arguments)
{
      System::Threading::Thread^ thr = gcnew System::Threading::Thread
      (gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &MainForm::Process));
      thr->IsBackground = true;
      thr->Start();

      while (true) {} //Test 1
    //while (true) { if (pt->TaskComplete) break; } //Test 2
 }
```

I do not want the MainForm::ButtonClick method to finish until the MainForm::Process has finished. That is why I put an inifinite loop at the end there. But no matter what I do, the GUI does not update until MainForm::ButtonClick returns.

I have read a lot of posts on Stack about using BGWorker or using BG thread. But as you can see, I have already called a thread in the background but the GUI does not change until the MainForm::ButtonClick ends. And I cannot let MainForm::ButtonClick to end until MainForm::Process has finished due to some reason that is irrelevant to this post.

Is there a way for me to UPDATE the labels of ProgressTracker from MainForm events without having the event methods to end first?

Edit - Whether the GUI updates or not is my secondary concern. What I am trying to actually understand here is why is it that the GUI does not update **until MainForm::ButtonClick returns** despite **MainForm::Process** being called from a BG thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**: GUI does not update until event method returns.

**Suggestions**: I have been suggested Background workers and threads.

So, none of the suggestions work because the readers appear to not understand the problem correctly. **THE GUI DOES NOT UPDATE UNTIL THE EVENT METHOD MainForm::ButtonClick RETURNS**. Emphasis on the "**UNTIL THE EVENT METHOD MainForm::ButtonClick RETURNS**" part. I have tried BG workers and threads but no matter what I do, the GUI will not update until the MainForm::ButtonClick method has finished execution.

**What is the problem?** I do not care if the GUI updates or not. What I need answers for is why is it that the GUI does not update **until MainForm::ButtonClick returns** despite **MainForm::Process** being called from a BG thread.

Current Solution: from **MainForm::ButtonClick**, call the **MainForm::Process** in a BG Worker or thread and then let **MainForm::Process** raise a separate even upon its completion.